# Elements do not flex in the column direction in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

See the holy grail demo here, http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/

If the body content is shorter than the window height the footer will rise up from the bottom of the page. This behavior does not happen in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: add `min-height` with some value you prefer to the "article", it can solve it.

Comment: @Eran there are techniques to make it look less bad, but it does not change flexbox is pretty broken in the column direction in IE11.

Comment: you right, this is not a directly solution but i thought it can help.  anyway, please check if this will help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600345/flexbox-and-internet-explorer-11-displayflex-in-html