# Why do absolutely positioned elements in a flexbox center properly on chrome but not IE11?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to get elements horizontally aligned in the center of a column, using a flexbox. It all works fine in Chrome but the items with position: absolute do not center in IE11.
Thanks!

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.not_centered{
  position: absolute;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="not_centered">
  text
  </div>
  <div class="not_centered">
  text 2
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="centered">
    centered
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32p7jsLx/7/)

Comment: That is because IE11 responds differently to `flexbox`. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600345/flexbox-and-internet-explorer-11-displayflex-in-html

Comment: doesn't look vertical aligned on chrome too ... can you add screenshots of actual vs expected and chrome vs IE ... Also which relation do you want between flexbox and absolute position ?

Comment: @AndrewLyndem thanks but none of those seem to work either

Comment: That's because IE stinks in every way shape and form.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Absolutely positioned elements are removed from flex layout, so you can't use flex properties on them anyway, except in a few rare cases.

Comment: @DaniP I can't add the links to the question, since apparently that takes more "reputation" than I have. Here's what it looks like in Chrome:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFSGq.png
And here's what it looks like in ie11: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlI73.png

Comment: @Michael_B all I would like is for it to appear the same in IE as it does in Chrome (if only I had a dollar for every time I've said that...)

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/32p7jsLx/10/

Comment: Awesome, thanks. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: Aaaa well that's Horizontal alignment ... I don't have IE xd

Comment: @DaniP this isn't a duplicate of that question... I'm asking specifically why flexbox behavior is inconsistent