# Flex image not displaying in IE 11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

With this code I am able to display a row like this in firefox and chrome.

[image]

In IE 11 it displays like this, and as you can see the image is not visible.

[image]

For some reason it seems to have no width in the inspector. How can I get it to work like it does in chrome and firefox? Thanks.

Code:

```
<div class="carousel-item active h-100 bg-dark text-light">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="text-center" style="flex:1;">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </div>
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/placeimg_320_400_animals.jpg') }}" class="d-block h-100"
            alt="..." style="flex:0;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure how to mark as duplicate, but I believe this is a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600345/flexbox-and-internet-explorer-11-displayflex-in-html - seems to have the answer at least.

Comment: @kilkfoe Thanks, replacing flex with flex-grow fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `flex` with `flex-grow` fixed this issue on IE 11.

```
<div class="carousel-item active h-100 bg-dark text-light">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="text-center" style="flex-grow:1;">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </div>
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/placeimg_320_400_animals.jpg') }}"
            class="d-block h-100" alt="..." style="flex-grow:0;">
    </div>
</div>
```