# Image inside flex parent is not overflowing in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

My image is acting strangely on Chrome and it gets shrunk. I am trying to achieve the effect like on Firefox but the image is not overflowing instead it shrinks down.

Here is my code. Check my second card image in chrome and in firefox:

```
<div class="card-group">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__imgContainer">
      <img class="card__img" src="https://www.pierrot-bg.com/images/news/2.jpg" alt="Меко казано" style="">
    </div>
    <div class="card__content">
      <h2 class="card__heading">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</h2>
      <div class="card__info">
        <span class="card__time"><span class="card__icon icon-calendar"></span>02.06.2019;</span>
        <span class="card__price"><span class="card__icon icon-price--sm"></span>8.00 лв; 10.00 лв; 12.00лв;</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card__buttons">
        <a class="button card__button" href="./spectacle.html">Виж повече</a>
        <a class="button button--plum button--buy card__button" href="">Купи билет <span class="button__icon icon-price"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__imgContainer">
      <img class="card__img" src="https://www.pierrot-bg.com/images/news/Meko-kazano_1.jpg" alt="Меко казано" style="">
    </div>
    <div class="card__content">
      <h2 class="card__heading">Lorem, ipsum.</h2>
      <div class="card__info">
        <span class="card__time"><span class="card__icon icon-calendar"></span>02.06.2019;</span>
        <span class="card__price"><span class="card__icon icon-price--sm"></span>8.00 лв; 10.00 лв; 12.00лв;</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card__buttons">
        <a class="button card__button" href="./spectacle.html">Виж повече</a>
        <a class="button button--plum button--buy card__button" href="">Купи билет <span class="button__icon icon-price"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

```
.card {
  & {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
  }
  &__imgContainer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  &__img {
    display: block;
    flex: 1 1 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  &__content {
    padding: 10px 30px 15px;
    background: #4821f5;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( 45deg, #4821f5 0%, #3b8dd4 100%);
    /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( 45deg, #4821f5 0%, #3b8dd4 100%);
    /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient( 45deg, #4821f5 0%, #3b8dd4 100%);
    /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#4821f5", endColorstr="#3b8dd4", GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
  }
  &__info {
    & {
      margin-top: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    &>* {
      display: block;
      font-size: 13px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    &>*+* {
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
  }
  &__icon {
    margin-right: 6px;
    line-height: inherit;
  }
  &__heading {
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 1;
  }
  &__buttons {
    & {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin: -8px;
    }
    &>* {
      margin: 8px;
    }
  }
  &__button {
    padding-top: 0.65em;
    padding-bottom: 0.65em;
  }
  &__textbox {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}

.card-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -1%;
  &>* {
    width: 31%;
    margin: 1%;
  }
}
```

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qmrshycg/)

I am expecting my image to act like in Firefox and to be cut like that and I don't want to use object-fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
}

.card__imgContainer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card__img {
  display: block;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card__content {
  padding: 10px 30px 15px;
  background: #4821f5;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #4821f5 0%, #3b8dd4 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #4821f5 0%, #3b8dd4 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #4821f5 0%, #3b8dd4 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#4821f5", endColorstr="#3b8dd4", GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}

.card__info {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card__info>* {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.card__info>*+* {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.card__icon {
  margin-right: 6px;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.card__heading {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.card__buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -8px;
}

.card__buttons>* {
  margin: 8px;
}

.card__button {
  padding-top: 0.65em;
  padding-bottom: 0.65em;
}

.card__textbox {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -1%;
}

.card-group>* {
  width: 31%;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-group">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__imgContainer">
      <img class="card__img" src="https://www.pierrot-bg.com/images/news/2.jpg" alt="Меко казано" style="">
    </div>
    <div class="card__content">
      <h2 class="card__heading">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</h2>
      <div class="card__info">
        <span class="card__time"><span class="card__icon icon-calendar"></span>02.06.2019;</span>
        <span class="card__price"><span class="card__icon icon-price--sm"></span>8.00 лв; 10.00 лв; 12.00лв;</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card__buttons">
        <a class="button card__button" href="./spectacle.html">Виж повече</a>
        <a class="button button--plum button--buy card__button" href="">Купи билет <span class="button__icon icon-price"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__imgContainer">
      <img class="card__img" src="https://www.pierrot-bg.com/images/news/Meko-kazano_1.jpg" alt="Меко казано" style="">
    </div>
    <div class="card__content">
      <h2 class="card__heading">Lorem, ipsum.</h2>
      <div class="card__info">
        <span class="card__time"><span class="card__icon icon-calendar"></span>02.06.2019;</span>
        <span class="card__price"><span class="card__icon icon-price--sm"></span>8.00 лв; 10.00 лв; 12.00лв;</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card__buttons">
        <a class="button card__button" href="./spectacle.html">Виж повече</a>
        <a class="button button--plum button--buy card__button" href="">Купи билет <span class="button__icon icon-price"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

`.card__img` had to be given a `height` of `100%` and `object-fit:cover`

Comment: I don't want to use object-fit because it's not supported in IE11. It was my old solution btw

Comment: Apologies. I didn't read your post script. I think this might help you out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22883146/2427237

Comment: This didn't help me. I just used object-fit with polyfill and now everything is fine. Thank you anyways.