# Why my visual interface doesn't work on IE 11 but yes it does in edge, chrome firefox etc.. display:flexbox could be the problem?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

There is a lot of things in my web project that doesn't work on IE 11.
I have tables inside of divs and that div have `display: flex` inside. They are shown well on all platforms but IE 11. In IE 11 seems to have height: 1px due to I don't really reach to see the table well.

I have another div that owns a table that I set invisibility hidden calling a function at the beginning of the rendering (not static, just check a state and then apply or not if it should be hidden or not) and I had checked by logs that should be hidden and it still appears like the other table.

I use `this.myDivTableContent.style= 'visibility: hidden';` to hide it that works perfectly in all other browsers.

I don't know what I have done bad but since I decided to see how in IE 11 works is like all project visual interface will have to be changed if I want to make work on it.

I let you 2 pictures to see the diff with chrome and IE 11.

CHROME:

[image]

IE11:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flexbox and Internet Explorer 11 (display:flex in <html>?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600345/flexbox-and-internet-explorer-11-displayflex-in-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
display: flex is partially supported by IE11.
```

When in doubt, you can use the site: https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Aflex

### You can use tables to avoid using flex

Look at this : https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/

### You can also try some polyfill like this :

You should change all you'r view but it will be a little more easy.

Comment: This is and absolute disaster for me, I have been programming the page months and  now I have to change all my views removing display: flex just to make IE works.

Comment: Compatibility with IE is the worst nightmare.. Good luck with that.

Comment: You can try some polyfill like this : https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility
You should change all you'r view but it will be a little more easy.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think I could use it, I prefer not to use anything more linked with Flex xD