# flex-wrap doesnt work in internet explorer

Tags: html, css

I have 4 boxes, its a standard 2 columns 2 rows boxes. Unfortunately I have to provide ie support. In internet explorer flex wrap isnt working so all the boxes are currently in one row and it looks very messy. Is there an alternative to flex wrap for this? The code is very basic and works in all browsers but not in ie.

```
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flexbox and Internet Explorer 11 (display:flex in <html>?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600345/flexbox-and-internet-explorer-11-displayflex-in-html)

Comment: none of the suggestions worked unfortunately

Comment: Which did you try and what specifically goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### flex-wrap in IE

#### Importances of `-webkit-box`

- There are several methods to fix the problem and the **best approach is adding prefixes**
- Flexbox for IE10, with `-ms-` prefix

```
{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

learn [Can i use](https://caniuse.com/flexbox)

try this ;)

```css
main { background: #E15555; } 
.wrap { 
   display: -webkit-box; 
   display: -ms-flexbox; 
   display: flex; 
   -webkit-box-align: center; 
      -ms-flex-align: center; 
         align-items: center; 
   -webkit-box-pack: center; 
      -ms-flex-pack: center; 
    justify-content: center; 
   max-width: 700px; 
   margin: 0 auto; 
   min-height: 100vh;
} 
.box { padding: 20px; } 
.content { 
    width:  100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background: #FEC8EE;
}
```

```html
<body>
<main> 
    <div class="wrap"> 
        <div class="box"> 
            <div class="content"></div> 
        </div> 
        <div class="box"> 
            <h1>Hola Amigo</h1> 
        </div> 
     </div>
</main>
</body>
```